# package.json modules installed at local paths can't be found at runtime

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, package.json

I have two packages in my package.json that have local paths:

```
"graphql-subscriptions": "../graphql-subscriptions",
"subscriptions-transport-ws": "../subscriptions-transport-ws"
```

After `npm install` they get correctly installed under `node_modules`. However when I run my node.js app, it gives me the following runtime error:

```
module.js:529
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'subscriptions-transport-ws'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:527:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:476:23)
    at Module.require (module.js:568:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/nbhati/projects/graphql-bookstore-server/src/app.factory.js:6:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:624:30)
    at loader (/Users/nbhati/projects/graphql-bookstore-server/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:144:5)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/Users/nbhati/projects/graphql-bookstore-server/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:154:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:545:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:508:12)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Make sure that you are requiring a file, or that the modules have `index.js` in them.

Comment: Is that `node_modules` folder in the same directory as your app (or in an ancestor directory)?

Comment: Thank you both. Yes I am importing the package and, yes the node_modules folder is just one level above the index.js of my app. I put the two packages in local path just because I am putting some console.log's in there for debugging. Otherwise if I get them directly from npm they work just fine with my code!

Comment: Mystery solved. Those packages were written in TypeScript. I had to compile them in order to be imported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mystery solved. Those packages were written in TypeScript. I had to compile them in order to be imported.